# Compare 2 arrays of objects, rename and delete all other objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays to rename some keys in the origin array. It works fine. Now I would like to remove all other objects which are not part of the array **types** without looping again. Thank you for your hints.

**Origin array:**

```
const annotations = [
{
    "componentId": "12334",
    "confidence": 0,
    "mappingMode": "original",
    "source": "plane",
    "uniqueId": "HS3233",
    "matchedTerm": "Plane",
    "begin": 0,
    "end": 6,
},
{
    ...
}
]
```

**Mapping array for renaming:**

```
const types = [
        {
            from : "uniqueID",
            to : "Identifier"
        }, 
        {
            from : "matchedTerm",
            to : "Matched text"
        },
        {
            from : "begin",
            to : "Begin"
        },
        {
            from : "end",
            to : "End"
        },
        {
            from : "dictCanon",
            to : "DictCanon"
        }
    ]
```

Now I rename all the keys included in the **type** array with:

```
    ...
    // rename keys
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        renameKeys(annotations, [ 
            {from: types[i].from, to: types[i].to }
        ]);
    }
    ...
    const renameKeys = (arr, nameMap) => {
    // loop around our array of objects
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var obj = arr[i];
      // loop around our name mappings
      for(var j = 0; j < nameMap.length; j++) {
         var thisMap = nameMap[j];
         if(obj.hasOwnProperty(thisMap.from)) {
           // found matching name
           obj[thisMap.to] = obj[thisMap.from];
           delete obj[thisMap.from];
         } 
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all the other properties of any object or remove object which don't have any keys from types array?

Comment: I would like to remove all other properties and its value if they are not included in the types array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code becomes simpler if you change your types array to a lookup table:

```js
const types = {
  "uniqueID": "Identifier",
  "matchedTerm": "Matched text",
  "begin": "Begin",
  "end": "End",
  "dictCanon": "DictCanon"
};

const items = [{
  "componentId": "12334",
  "confidence": 0,
  "mappingMode": "original",
  "source": "plane",
  "uniqueId": "HS3233",
  "matchedTerm": "Plane",
  "begin": 0,
  "end": 6,
}];

let convertedItems = [];

for (let item of items) {
  let convertedItem = {};
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    if (key in types) convertedItem[types[key]] = value;
  }
  convertedItems.push(convertedItem);
}

console.log(convertedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array higher order functions to simplify problem

```
const types = {
  "uniqueId": "Identifier",
  "matchedTerm": "Matched text",
  "begin": "Begin",
  "end": "End",
  "dictCanon": "DictCanon"
};

const items = [
  {
  "componentId": "12334",
  "confidence": 0,
  "mappingMode": "original",
  "source": "plane",
  "uniqueId": "HS3233",
  "matchedTerm": "Plane",
  "begin": 0,
  "end": 6,
},
  {
  "componentId": "64645",
  "confidence": 8,
  "mappingMode": "original",
  "source": "plane",
  "uniqueId": "565",
  "matchedTerm": "Plane",
  "begin": 15,
  "end": 36,
},
  {
  "componentId": "9+8984861",
  "confidence": 20,
  "mappingMode": "original",
  "source": "plane",
  "uniqueId": "HS32KEIK33",
  "matchedTerm": "Plane",
  "begin": 40,
  "end": 22,
},
];

const newItems = [];
items.map(item => {
  const newItemObj = {};
    Object.keys(item).filter(each => {
      if(types[each])
        newItemObj[types[each]] = item[each];
    })
    newItems.push(newItemObj);
  });
```